# Cannot read property scrollToBottom of null after revisiting a page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, scrollto

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4

Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7

Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47

ios-deploy version: Not installed

ios-sim version: Not installed

OS: Windows 7

Node Version: v6.9.2

Xcode version: Not installed
```

Im getting this error after Im pushing to a Conversation-View. With socketIO im connecting to my messageserver which is pushing new messages to the client. After this I want to automatically scroll down, so the newest message will be displayed.

If i open the conv.-window for the first time im good with it and all is working fine, but on the second time (pressing back and renavigating to the page) i got this error.

Thank you :)

EDIT: Error-Message:

> Cannot read property scrollToBottom of null

```
connect() {
  this.socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected");  
      console.log("Listening on: "+"message_"+this.secretid);
      this.socket.emit('message', { type: "token", token: this.secretid });
      this.socket.on("message_"+this.secretid, (msg) => {
          let msg_data = JSON.parse(msg);
          msg_data.payload.writer_id = msg_data.payload.user;
          console.log(msg_data);
          this.chat.push(msg_data.payload);
          this.content.scrollToBottom(); <<--Error
      });
  });
}
```

Connect is called in `ionViewDidLoad() {}` so `this.content` should be initialized.

Im using ionic 2

EDIT 2: Only getting this error in Ionic Lab

Comment: what is `content`  and where is it saet?

Comment: @ViewChild(Content) content:Content; --> <ion-content></ion-content>

Comment: I could be more specific based on the code you can show

Answer (score 1):

`ionviewdidload` lifecycle hook is called for page initialisation and is called once. [Docs here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)

The view may not be loaded yet.

From the given code,the solution I see is either put the scrollTobottom call in `ionviewWillEnter`

or try Angular's hook `ngOnChanges` [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges) where you can check for change in chat list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-content #content>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your this.content.scrollToBottom(0); under **if condition**. Like this :

> if( this.content._scroll ) 
>   {
>
> ```
> this.content.scrollToBottom(0);
> ```
>
> }

Please try it once.